# r.stream.order returns error

Tags: grass-gis

GRASS Version 8.3
OS Win 10

I have a python script that I am using to process data to create hydro outputs, in the past it has worked without error but recently it has returned an error.

The script returns an error when I attempt to run r.stream.order

```
gs.run_command('r.stream.order', stream_rast=stream_raster, direction='flowdir', elevation=input_raster, accumulation='flowacc', stream_vect='stream_vect', strahler='strahler', overwrite=True)
```

The error occurs at v_run==6 in the script below;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import grass.script as gs
import os
import shutil
#import subprocess

# workflow variables
v_aoi='2023_LIDAR'
v_project_folder='F:/_HYDRO_STUDIES/'+v_aoi
v_output_vector = v_project_folder+'/VECTOR_OUT'
v_run=6

def main():

#Cleanup folders
    if v_run == 1:
        shutil. rmtree(v_output_vector)
        os.mkdir(v_output_vector)

#Import DTM
    if v_run == 2:
        gs.run_command('r.in.gdal',flags='o', input=v_project_folder+'/RASTER_IN/DTM_420000_6190000.tif', output='dtm', overwrite=True)
        gs.run_command('g.region', flags='p', rast='dtm')

#Fill
    if v_run == 3:
        gs.run_command('r.fill.dir',input='dtm',output='fill',direction='flowdir',overwrite=True)

#Accumulation
    if v_run == 4:
       gs.run_command('r.watershed', flags='sa', elevation='fill', threshold=400, accumulation='flowacc', overwrite=True)

#Streams
    if v_run == 5:
       gs.run_command('r.stream.extract', elevation='dtm', threshold=3000, stream_raster='stream_ras', stream_vector='stream_vec', direction='flowdir', overwrite=True)

#Classification (inc strahler)
    if v_run == 6:
       gs.run_command('r.stream.order',stream_rast='stream_ras',direction='flowdir',elevation='dtm',accumulation='flowacc',stream_vect='stream_vec',strahler='strahler_ord',overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('v.out.ogr', input='stream_vec', type='line', output=v_output_vector+'/stream_lin.gpkg', overwrite=True)

#Basins
    if v_run == 7:
       gs.run_command('r.watershed', flags='sa', elevation='fill', threshold=20000, drainage='raster_drainage', basin='raster_basin', overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('r.to.vect', flags='s', input='raster_basin', output='vector_basin', type='area', overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('v.out.ogr', flags='c', input='vector_basin', type='area', output=v_output_vector+'/'+'basin_20k_ply.gpkg', overwrite=True)

    if v_run == 7:
       gs.run_command('r.watershed', flags='sa', elevation='fill', threshold=200000, drainage='raster_drainage', basin='raster_basin', overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('r.to.vect', flags='s', input='raster_basin', output='vector_basin', type='area', overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('v.out.ogr', flags='c', input='vector_basin', type='area', output=v_output_vector+'/'+'basin_200k_ply.gpkg', overwrite=True)

    if v_run == 7:
       gs.run_command('r.watershed', flags='sa', elevation='fill', threshold=400000, drainage='raster_drainage', basin='raster_basin', overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('r.to.vect', flags='s', input='raster_basin', output='vector_basin', type='area', overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('v.out.ogr', flags='c', input='vector_basin', type='area', output=v_output_vector+'/'+'basin_400k_ply.gpkg', overwrite=True)

    if v_run == 7:
       gs.run_command('r.watershed', flags='sa', elevation='fill', threshold=800000, drainage='raster_drainage', basin='raster_basin', overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('r.to.vect', flags='s', input='raster_basin', output='vector_basin', type='area', overwrite=True)
       gs.run_command('v.out.ogr', flags='c', input='vector_basin', type='area', output=v_output_vector+'/'+'basin_800k_ply.gpkg', overwrite=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

And this is the error code returned in the GRASS console

```
(Thu Aug 24 14:24:42 2023)                                                      
F:\hydro_db\FEA\PERMANENT\.tmp/unknown\13048.0.py                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\hydro_db\FEA\PERMANENT\.tmp\unknown\13048.0.py",
line 133, in <module>
    main()
  File "F:\hydro_db\FEA\PERMANENT\.tmp\unknown\13048.0.py",
line 77, in main
    gs.run_command('r.stream.order',stream_rast='stream_ras'
,direction='flowdir',elevation='dtm',accumulation='flowacc',
stream_vect='stream_vec',strahler='strahler_ord',overwrite=T
rue)
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
8.3\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 466, in
run_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, result=None, args=args,
kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
8.3\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line 345, in
handle_errors
    raise CalledModuleError(module=module, code=code,
returncode=returncode)
grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run
`r.stream.order --o stream_rast=stream_ras direction=flowdir
elevation=dtm accumulation=flowacc stream_vect=stream_vec
strahler=strahler_ord` ended with an error.
The subprocess ended with a non-zero return code:
3221225781. See errors above the traceback or in the error
output.
(Thu Aug 24 14:24:43 2023) Command ended with non-zero return code 1 (0 sec)
```